# Why isn't my 'Menu' bar displaying in my JFrame 'Window' Object?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Here I've created the JFrame object, 'window'. And set it to 'true'.

```
import java.awt.*;

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("GUI Test");

    window.setSize(250, 100);
    window.setLocation(100, 100);

    window.setVisible(true);
```

Here I've added menu items to the 'menu'. And set visibility  as 'true'.

```
    JMenuItem home = new JMenuItem("Home");
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    JMenuItem tag = new JMenuItem("Tag");

    JMenu menu = new JMenu("menu");
    menu.add(home);
    menu.add(about);
    menu.add(tag);

    menu.setVisible(true);  


}
```

I'm not getting any errors. Then what am I missing? Why doesn't my menu display in the 'window' object?

Comment: You never add the menu too the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frirst creat JMenubar and add the JMenu into that.

```
 JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
```

Add the JMenu into JMenuBar and JMenuar into JFrame to display in the window.

```
menubar.add(menu);
window.setJMenuBar(menubar);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your `JMenu`s to a `JMenuBar` and set to to the `JFrame` using `JFrame#setJMenuBar`

See [How to use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `JMenuBar` with window,

```
 JMenuBar menuBar= new JMenuBar();

 .....
 menuBar.add(menu);//Add menu with JMenuBar.

 window.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Jmenu` into in you `JFrame`

```
window.add(menu);
```

and also set the layout to `JFrame`

```
window.setLayout(new Flawlayout()); // you can try other layout too
```

And best way is

[How to use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)